# Display Google Patent summary for non-US documents

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to make a formal request to support Google Patent sidebar summaries for non-US patent number tags, especially WIPO patent tags.

This is peripherally related to a question regarding expected [sidebar behavior with multiple patent number tags](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/279/14417).